# Expanding an Excel formula without referencing the previous cell

Tags: excel, reference, row, cell, formula

I am attempting to use an IF statement to check whether the sum of two cells from another Excel sheet is greater than or equal to 1.

For a sheet called `Test1` with the values of interest in column `C`, this is what I have so far, which works fine:
`=IF((Test1!C1+Test1!C2>=1),1,0)`

In column `B` on a second sheet that I'll call `Test2`, I want to copy this formula down `200,000` rows. However, if the aforementioned formula is in cell `B1`, for the formula in `B2` I would like the formula to read:
`=IF((Test1!C3+Test1!C4>=1),1,0)`

I want to copy the formula down the column so that the second cell reference in the formula in the first row does not become the first cell reference in the formula in the second row (eg. it would go `C1+C2`, then `C3+C4`, `C5+C6`, etc.).

I have tried manually entering the formula for a few rows, highlighting those, and copying them down but can't get the desired cell reference pattern. If I highlight and drag these first three formulae down another three rows, `C4` and `C5` are repeated and not in the correct pair.

```
=IF((Test1!C1+Test1!C2>=1),1,0)

=IF((Test1!C3+Test1!C4>=1),1,0)

=IF((Test1!C5+Test1!C6>=1),1,0)

=IF((Test1!C4+Test1!C5>=1),1,0)

=IF((Test1!C6+Test1!C7>=1),1,0)

=IF((Test1!C8+Test1!C9>=1),1,0)
```

I have tried using `OFFSET()` within this formula but couldn't get it to work. I am basically just wanting to add `1` to each of the cell references in the formula, as compared to the previous row (but not to actually add `1` to the value of that cell, as would happen with `C1+1` for example).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan on copying this down 200K rows then you will want the absolute simplest formula that accomplishes the stagger. Avoid the volatile [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) or be prepared to spend a lot of time waiting for random calculation cycles to complete. A volatile function will recalculate whenever *anything* in the workbook changes; not just when something changes that involved the formula in the cell.

```
 =--(SUM(INDEX(Test1!C:C, (ROW(1:1)-1)*2+1), INDEX(Test1!C:C, (ROW(1:1)-1)*2+2))>=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding an IF statement to this worked perfectly for what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula should do the trick:

```
=(SUM(INDIRECT("C"&ROW()*2-1);INDIRECT("C"&ROW()*2))>=1)*1
```

And that's the version using `IF`:

```
=IF(SUM(INDIRECT("C"&ZEILE()*2-1);INDIRECT("C"&ROW()*2))>=1;1;0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You say *I am basically just wanting to add '1' to each of the cell references in the formula* but appear to be incrementing by `2`, so I am confused but an option might be to apply you existing formula to 400,000 rows, together with `=ISODD(ROW())` in another column, then filter on that other column to select and delete those showing `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Excel's autofill won't do the 2-cell shift that you're looking for.  You can use the functionality that is there.

Put `=IF((Test1!C1+Test1!C2>=1),1,0)` in the top cell and drag a copy to the second row (it will be `=IF((Test1!C2+Test1!C3>=1),1,0)` but that's okay).  Now, put 'A' and 'B' in the next column.  Select all 4 cells and copy them down 400k rows.

Use filter to delete rows flagged with 'B' and delete the blank rows.

(Select blank rows with `[F5]` click `Special` and select `Blanks`, then right-click and delete)

Answer (score 0):

Here is all you need. It's fast and nonvolatile.

```
=--(SUM(INDEX(Test1!C:C,ROW(1:1)*2-2):INDEX(Test1!C:C,ROW(2:2)*2-2))>=1)
```

Copy it down as far as you like.